# Webflow: it's possible to switch between flows?

Tags: grails, spring-webflow, grails-2.2

I have two controllers and each one have a flow. In my menu I have a link to the flows. If I'm in flow #1 and click in the link of the flow #2, Grails will show me the view of the flow #1.

The only way I found to make this transition work was to have a link to an action that redirects to the flow.

```
class FirstController {
  def firstFlow = {
  }

  def toFirst() {
    redirect action: 'first'
  }

}

class SecondController {
  def secondFlow = {
  }
  def toSecond() {
    redirect action: 'second'
  }
}
```

- Going to `/first/first` shows the view correctly.
- Going to `/second/second` shows the view of **first**.
- Going to `/second/toSecond` redirects and show the view correctly.
- Backing to `/first/first` shows the view of **second**
- Goingo to `/first/toFisrt` shows the view correctly.

Is this a expected behavior? Why the flow don't go to the correct view?

**EDIT**

The menu is created using [Platform Core Navigation API](http://grailsrocks.github.io/grails-platform-core/guide/nav.html).

```
navigation = {
  app {
    first(controller: 'first', action: 'first', title: 'nav.exportar')
    second(controller: 'second', action: 'second', title: 'nav.importar')
  }
}
```

**Links**

```
http://localhost:8080/my-application/first/first?execution=e14s1
http://localhost:8080/my-application/second/second?execution=e14s1
```

Comment: how does your link to the other flow look like or how do you create it ?

Comment: @johnSmith I edited the question with the menu info.

Comment: I might be mistaken here, but the execution url(e14s1) is the same for both, shouldn't be different if you are having 2 different flows? maybe thats why its overstepping the other flow

Comment: What code do you have in each flow of both controllers?

Comment: @dmahapatro Bounty hunter? :-) See the controllers in the question. I think you can simulate the issue using them. The original controllers have too much code to show here.

Answer (score 0):

If we want to cease a flow process (like clicking menu), we need to tell webflow `end-state`.

so the menu link url should include `eventId` parameter that means `end-state`.

I don't know navigation api, but `g:link` example below:

```
<g:if test="${params.action=='first'}"><%-- we are in first flow. --%>
    <g:link event="toSecond">Go to second</g:link>
</g:if>
<g:else><%-- we are not in first flow, normal link. --%>
    <g:link controller="second" action="second">Go to second</g:link>
</g:else>
```

and first controller:

```
class FirstController {
    def firstFlow = {
        // view-state
        firstViewState {
            on('next').to 'nextAction'
            on('toSecond').to 'toSecond' // <g:link event='toSecond'> in gsp
        }

        // end-state
        toSecond() {
            redirect (controller:'second', action:'second')
        }
    }

    def toFirst() {
        redirect action: 'first'
    }
}
```